# Julia: How does GCP Cloud Build uses a different DEPOT_PATH?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, julia, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run a simple Julia HTTP server on Google Cloud Run.

So I test the application offline by running the docker using `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 test-julia` which works perfectly fine (I built the image with the tag of `test-julia` obviously).

But when I do `gcloud run deploy` it complains about package HTTP not installed which is clearly installed in the Dockerfile!

After much digging, it was found that when I run Julia on GCP, it looks for packages in `/home/.julia` but the installation of the package happens in `/root/.julia`.

I think it's to do with how GCP handles the `CMD` command in Docker. Does GCP force a change of the work directory or something when I run it? What's causing the issues on GCP?

Of course I can fix the issue by just setting `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` so the installation and searching of packages go to the same directory.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM julia:latest

ENV JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=/home/.julia

RUN julia -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.add("HTTP"); println(DEPOT_PATH)'

COPY server.jl server.jl

CMD [ "julia", "server.jl"]
```

**server.jl**

```
using HTTP

PORT = 8080
if haskey(ENV, "PORT")
    PORT = parse(Int, ENV["PORT"])
end

println("Listening on port $PORT")

server = HTTP.serve("0.0.0.0", PORT) do request::HTTP.Request
   try
       return HTTP.Response("Hello")
   catch e
       return HTTP.Response(400, "Error: $e")
   end
end

#close(server)
```

Comment: Yeah, they're probably setting a default USER or something, so when it goes to run, it's looking in a specific user's home directory for the depot path and not the root where you built things. That's definitely weird though.